# Questions about Small Business environments on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Are small business environment questions on topic for SU, or should they be put onto SF (with a server)?

Just in case anyone is wondering, the question is https://serverfault.com/questions/352137/connecting-vista-win7-clients-to-sbs2011-ad

Comment: Like what type of questions are you talking of here?

Comment: @random Questions on small networks, but still a business environment. Specifically, I have a question about a network with 5 users and Windows SBS 2011

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote partially from the Super User FAQ:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   **question about**…
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> - **issues *specific* to corporate IT support and networks**

If you're asking about things like configuring your servers, business grade networking equipment, computer imaging on a large scale, etc. then your questions are probably better suited to Server Fault. But questions about computer hardware and software that *happen* to be in a small business environment are fine.  Questions should only go on Stack Overflow if they're about programming.

If you have some specific examples of questions you aren't sure about, edit your question to include them and I can address those. In general though, if your question would be mostly the same regardless of whether you're asking for a small business or in your home, it's fine.

To quote the Server Fault FAQ:

> Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support
>   professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a
>   professional capacity. If your question is about …
>
> - Servers
> - Networks
> - Desktop PCs that you maintain in the workplace
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - Networking outside the professional workplace
> - Running servers at home for personal use
> - General personal computer troubleshooting
> - Product or service recommendations
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Nowhere in there does it say "you can't ask questions about a small business". If you're managing the computers for a small business, that qualifies as "people who manage computers in a professional capacity". I see no reason you couldn't ask questions about Windows SBS on Server Fault. In fact, there are over 150 questions on SF [tagged windows-sbs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs).

Comment: My question is about Windows SBS 2011, which would be replaced by WHS 2011 if in the home. It seems like a middle-groud between SF and SU

Comment: @Luke questions about SBS would almost certainly be more appropriate for SF.

Comment: I agree, SBS should be on SF, as you will get better and more expert answers there.

Comment: @Luke see my edits above. SBS questions would be much better suited to SF than SU.

Comment: @nhinkle Thanks, I for some reason thought if it was less than 50 users, it couldn't go there. Thanks