# Are questions about business servers operated for personal purposes on topic here?

Tags: discussion, migration, allowed-topics

I came across [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/695916/reinstall-embedded-megaraid-configuration-manager-in-a-cisco-ucs-m3-c22-rackmoun), which is specific to rackmount server hardware. On first glance, this question would appear to be best for Server Fault because SF specializes in business computer systems. However, when I commented that the post belongs on SF, I got the following response from the OP:

> Server Fault gets mad at me when I post because I am not a "professional." – Dudemcman

It is now apparent that the server is being used for personal purposes. Are such questions on topic for Super User?

Comment: I can see how this sort of question would not be the best for SU, but I am not aware of a better place for questions relating to enterprise and business class hardware for personal use and/or individuals who are not professionals.

Comment: yes it is. [Questions about Small Business environments on topic?](http://meta.superuser.com/a/4091)

Comment: @Dudemcman: I have retracted the close vote on your question.

Comment: @DragonLord Glad we could get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Cool, my question is linked :) If only it was worth extra rep... ;)